# How to break pinia store into individual files?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I am using pinia to manage state into my Vue3 app. There has been thorough discussion [here](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/802#issuecomment-1018780409) to break pinia store into individual files like state, getters, actions. But I am looking for a more 'stable' and 'elegant' solution to break the pinia store into individual files.

Comment: This isn't recommended because this will disable type inference for the store. Even if you don't use TS, it's useful in IDE. The habit to break them comes from Redux that suffers from boilerplate problem. This isn't the case here.

Comment: There is a discussion here: https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/802

Comment: It's moved to the discussion https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/1324